# multiple name match the pattern

Tags: regex, perl, unix

**Input file:File name='sample1.txt'**

1. lion is a good friend (Host=lion) (Port=animal) and tiger is
   (Host=Tiger)(Port=an)
2. burger is a food (Host=Burger)(Port=Food)

I have data as shown in the above txt file.I want to collect the host and port in each line from a txt file and place them in new txt file

**Required Outfile:**

- lion:animal
- Tiger:an
- Burger:Food

**Code used till nw:**

```
cat sample1.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1=$2\n" if(/Host=([\w.]*.'-'*[\w.]*.).*Port=(\d+)/)' > sample2.txt

sed 's|[()]||g' sample2.txt > sample3.txt
```

**Obtained output:**

- lion:animal
- Burger:Food

**Not getting the Tiger and an:**

**Problem** : I am not able to get the host and port in same line which is present more then once..i some line it have only one host and port value..in other line there are more than one host and port value..pls help me to slove this ..thank you ..:)

Comment: `perl -ne 'Host=(\w+).*Port=(\w+)/g && print "$1=$2\n";'` - based on your sample data. Useful trick - you can match on a negative if you want "everything up to a bracket" as `[^)]+` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have all entries in the order of appearance, you can use something like that:

```
perl -nle 's{Host=([^)]*).*?Port=([^)]*)}{print "$1:$2"}ge' < sample1.txt > sample3.txt
```

Comment: why are you using greater than 'ge' in the code....and
^ mean beginning of the string what does [^)] means ..thanks

Comment: At the beginning of a character class `^` means negation. So `[^)]` means any character except `)`.

Comment: And `ge` here are the modifiers of `s///` regular expression replace. `g` means global so you match every occurrence (without it you would match only first one as in your question), `e` means execute the replacement string and paste the result (instead of pasting the string itself). I recommend reading http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html :)